# Who is responsible for ensuring that 18+ content is not shown to minors: the site or the user?

Tags: united-states, pornography

Websites generally want to prevent minors from viewing 18+ content, but if a minor does access the content, is the minor legally responsible or is the website legally responsible, and what are the legal consequences? What measures is the website legally required to take? These are a few examples to consider:

- A website only shows a warning against 18+ content on its home page, but fails to show it on any subpages (no account needs to be created to view the content).
- A website says in its Terms of Service that viewers must be age 18 or older, but does not show any warnings, expecting users to check the Terms and leave immediately if the user is a minor. The home page itself does not have 18+ content.
- A website shows an 18+ warning before viewing content and requires users to click that they are at least 18 years old and would like to view 18+ content.
- A website requires users to create an account and provide their birthdate, but does not require an actual ID, before viewing 18+ content.

No financial transactions take place.

Comment: Who is required to prevent underage alcohol sales and consumption, the bar or the punter?  Same issue, just in terms people understand better.

Comment: @Moo no, not the same issue unless the Internet access is on devices made available to the general public (such as those in Internet cafes).  If parents own the devices, the issues are different because the transactions are made by the parents rather than by the minors themselves.

Comment: @Moo You can probably enter an 18+ site just by clicking a button saying that you are old enough, but if you go into a bar and say that you are age 21 and the bar makes no attempt to check ID, I would think that the bar may be liable. Also, no financial transactions are occurring in the scenario described above.

Comment: @grovkin This scenario assumes no money is transferred, so there are no "transactions".

Comment: @joseph-parsons pointless click-through affirmations are starting to become very inadequate in new laws in many countries - they offer no actual barrier, so they offer no actual protection now.  They are exactly the equivalent of the barman asking the punter "are you legally allowed to buy alcohol" without checking ID.

Comment: There is a transaction.  The purchasing of Internet-access services and the devices for accessing the service are transactions.  Parents have the options of restricting access on those devices.  It's not different from television devices.  The fact that such services are not in wide use is a market place decision.  V-chip is available to restrict children from watch porn on tv, too.  But it's not widely used.

Comment: @Moo However, I would assume that a bar would need to check ID before serving anyone alcohol, so if the bar doesn't check ID, it is the bar's fault. However, I would assume that websites would not be required to check ID. So, wouldn't they have different legal standards?

Comment: @joseph-parsons where Im from, there is no law saying a bar must check ID, but there is a law saying its illegal to serve alcohol to under 18s.  Similarly theres a law about showing indecent material to minors.  In both cases the limit is simple, but the protective measures are something the venue decides on.  Websites choose not to ask for ID.  Bars choose to ask for ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website can arbitrarily decide that it will not allow access to any person under 18. The minor violating the TOS in that case would bear whatever the legal consequences fall upon them, by being sued by the website owner.

For most if not all cases of so-called "18+" content, the restriction relates to laws regarding dissemination of obscene materials to minors. There are various state laws against disseminating obscene material to anyone, and additionally, federal laws against disseminating obscene materials to minors, see [47 USC 223(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/223). It is extremely unclear what constitutes "obscene" material (this is determined by the jury), so while porn may be legal, there *is* a risk in allowing a minor to view porn, because there is an increased risk that content that is deemed to be legal to show to an adult may be deemed obscene when shown to a minor. Out of an abundance of caution, a website operator may therefore try to filter out minors from the viewing audience.

Here is the logical flow of the relevant federal law. 1: A website cannot send obscene material to a minor. 2: Nor can they make it available for a minor to see. However, both provisions are subject to a "knowingly" provision, thus accidentally making obscene material available is not a violation of the law. Additionally, subsection (e)(5) provides defenses, one that the person

> has taken, in good faith, reasonable, effective, and appropriate
> actions under the circumstances to restrict or prevent access by
> minors to a communication specified in such subsections, which may
> involve any appropriate measures to restrict minors from such
> communications, including any method which is feasible under available
> technology

or

> has restricted access to such communication by requiring use of a
> verified credit card, debit account, adult access code, or adult
> personal identification number

And furthermore, (6):

> The Commission may describe measures which are reasonable, effective,
> and appropriate to restrict access to prohibited communications under
> subsection (d).

(The "Commission" is the FCC). There are apparently no such regulations.

There are related laws such as [18 USC 1470](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1470) which criminalize transferring obscene material to anyone under age *16*, which also has a "knowingly" requirement. There are [laws against tricking children](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2252C) into viewing "harmful" content by using misleading names, but the law also says that "a word or digital image that clearly indicates the sexual content of the site, such as 'sex' or 'porn', is not misleading".

In short, in a hypothetical cases where some content is *labeled* "18+", there are no legal consequences for the website operator unless the material is actually deemed to be obscene. In that case, the operator would have to make a reasonable attempt to exclude minors, such as by requiring a customer to be 18+ to view the site.

Comment: I think these laws were passed before Internet filters existed.  And the existence of such filters made them legally moot.

Comment: "For most if not all cases of so-called "18+" content, the restriction relates to laws regarding dissemination of obscene materials to minors" Not true. Laws can and do prohibit furnishing non-obscene but sexual content to minors that adults have a protected right toi receive.

Comment: Suppose that the material is deemed to be obscene. What would "a reasonable attempt" be (which of the bullet point examples would be considered a reasonable attempt)?

Comment: @DavidSiegel the warnings, which can be easily bypassed by lying, don't exclusively serve the purpose of gate-keeping.  They also allow for Internet filters on devices to block such content.  Failure to install filters on personal devices purchased by parents is a personal choice.  Again, the burden for creating blocks, at the point of origination of content, only existed at the time when the Internet filters were not available.

Comment: @grovkin the various laws have not, as far as I know, changed. Whatever burdens they imposed, they still impose. ,The possible availability of filters (which is far from recent) is not, I think legally significant at all.  I have not yet researched the laws to see what burdens they impose, and then there is the question of decisions to enforce such laws as exist.

Comment: @DavidSiegel the laws have not changed.  But the availability of the filters (I think, but I am not completely certain) changes the fact pattern wrt those laws.

Comment: As determined in [*Reno v. ACLU*](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1996/96-511), 47 USC 223(d) is unconstitutional and cannot be enforced at all.

Comment: In aid of general clarify, SCOTUS overturned 'CDA's "indecent transmission" and "patently offensive display" provisions (which) abridge "the freedom of speech" protected by the First Amendment", and the current §223(d) has been amended by Congress to comply with that ruling.

Comment: So, aside from the website deciding to sue, which is not very likely, the minor would not be legally liable at all? And what damages would the website sue for?